# How to change position of social login button?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, extensions

I have installed an extension providing **social login with Magento 1.9 on the create account page.**

....

It's working well. But I want to change its position. So how I can change it?

...........

It's structure is as below:

**Layout :->    frontend/layout/mini_orangae_openid.xml**

**Template :-> frontend/template/mini_orange**

Comment: Please provide layout file code or link of extension for help. And where you have to move button?

Comment: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/social-login-30.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the this file

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/miniorange_openid`

and change the position By your own as this file its checking the condition and add just like below code

```
<?php if($facebookShareEnable){ 
$link = 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=766555246789034&amp;display=popup&amp;href='.$url.'&amp;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fminiorange.com%2Fsocial_share_redirect'; ?><i class="mo_custom_sharing_icon_preview fa fa-facebook" id="mo_custom_sharing_icon_preview_facebook"  style="color:#fff;text-align:center;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:<?php echo $marginBottom;?>px;display:inline-block;padding-top:<?php echo $paddingTop;?>px;height:<?php echo $shareIconSize;?>px;width:<?php echo $shareIconSize;?>px;font-size:<?php echo $fontSize;?>px;border-radius:<?php echo $borderRadius;?>px; margin-left:<?php echo $shareIconSpace;?>px;background:<?php echo $shareIconCustomColor;?>" onclick="popupCenter('<?php echo $link; ?>', 800, 400);"></i>
<?php }
```

if you want  this after twitter then put this code after twitter code .

> plesae take backup of this file before you change

Comment: You are always Welcome :)